# ASP.NET need to implement DatePicker

Tags: asp.net

I been used to Telerik's datepicker.

What I need to do in just plain asp.net controls is to implement a datepicker.
What is the easiest way to implement a datepicker in asp.net?

Comment: Is your page using some type of Javascript library?

Comment: <input type="date" /> is a cool alternative, but AFAIK it displays picker only in Webkit

Comment: Why are you stopping using Telerik? That might help us know what things to recommend and what you can and can't use. There is no "plain" ASP.NET control out of the box with date picker features. But the Ajax Control Toolkit's CalendarExtender and the jQuery UI datepicker are both free.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `Ajax` try the [Ajax Date Picker](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx).